# how to add thinckness to complex geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Iam modeling a top for a 3D printed toy car. I started from a mirrored plane, so it now has no thickness. If I use solidify modifier it makes a lot of bad geometry and intersecting faces. Making it manually seems like to much work. Is there a right or balanced way to add thickness to this model so it can be 3D printed?
[image]

Comment: you could test extrusion and its different options to see if it makes a difference, it will probably need to rework a bit anyway

Comment: Hello :). The solidify modifier has a 'complex' setting with different options. It often gives better results, but may still require manual tweaking in the end.

Comment: @JachymMichal yep, already tried that, it has much better results, but still makes intersections. I feel like there should be more options when adding thickness, like merging geometry and preventing geometry from penetrating in the corners and so on.